# I am trying following query and getting unexpected token : in exception

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public boolean insert(Product product){       
        boolean result = true;
        Transaction tx = null; 
        int quantity=0;
        try {
            tx = session.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();

            Query query=session.createQuery("update Stock s set s.quantity=s.quantity+100");
            query.executeUpdate();
            session.saveOrUpdate(product); 

            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            result=false;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }        
        return result;
}
```

select ,save and delete query are working successfully but This exception I am getting only in while update the record....

I want to save the record in Product Table and as well as update Stock Table

**BELOW IS MY EXCEPTION**

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:8: unexpected token: in
Sep 12, 2015 10:34:41 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:8: unexpected token: in
line 1:8: unexpected token: in
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.updateStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
    at in.edu.pondiuni.service.ProductService.insert(ProductService.java:23)
    at in.edu.pondiuni.controller.ProductServlet.processRequest(ProductServlet.java:53)
    at in.edu.pondiuni.controller.ProductServlet.doGet(ProductServlet.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: I tried executing a similar query as yours: no problem. The only way I managed to replicate your error message was by executing `update in User u set ...`. So you're probably not executing the query you posted, and your *actual* query has a `in` keyword that shouldn't be there.

Comment: If sure of the executed query, I would try using another package name, `in` is a reserved keyword and that *might* be the issue (that would correspond to position 8 "UPDATE in.edu.pondiuni.xxx.Stock")

Comment: @RC. good catch. That must be it. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @RC how plz details it

Comment: @JBNizet I did, thanks, but that's just an hypothesis. Aashish, I did try to explain "how" in my answer, your IDE might be helpful in doing the package rename (with intellij there is a refactoring to rename: Shift-F6 on osx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If sure of the executed query, I would try using another package name, `in` is a reserved keyword and that *might* be the issue, that would correspond to position 8:

```
UPDATE in.edu.pondiuni.xxx.Stock
       ^
       8
```

To do so, a search and replace in your codebase of `in.edu.pondiuni` should do the job, you can replace it with `edu.pondiuni` for example.

Comment: No it's not working and token: in is not in from package name it is by default because not a single time i use 'in' in my whole project even when i  remove in from package then it's same execption

Comment: Can you share the whole project?

Comment: Yes i can but how i will atach it in comment

Comment: Maybe you could post it to github or share an archive somehow (dropbox, ...)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6j1o9dcpbf1h08u/AAAeTpHlg7erN_Lv5Q14Hwyga?dl=0      **In productService.java I need when insert record in Product table then it should be updated in Stock table and if product_name does not present then insert the record in stock table**

Comment: OK, so you know what a package is? You have to remove "in." from your package name, that's not the case in your shared project. see http://tinypic.com/r/2n1ur15/8

Comment: thanks buddy it's working perfectly   but i want to know why it was problem in "in." package

Comment: Because `IN` is a reserved SQL keyword like in `UPDATE foo SET bar = 2 WHERE id IN (?)` and hibernate parser mistakenly takes your `in` from the package name for the `IN` keyword.